# How to link account to pricebook

Tags: custom-field, account, pricebook

I'm working on an application in which it should be possible to link an account to a pricebook. Because for different accounts, different prices may be appropriate. Is there a way to directly link an account to a pricebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An opportunity is related to a PriceBook via the PriceBook2Id lookup. An Opportunity is tied to an an Account.

You could create a text field on Account, PriceBookId__c and stamp the id of the PriceBook permitted. Then have a validation rule on Opportunity which only permits a PriceBook whose Id matches the value stamped on the Account.

```
PriceBook2Id != Account.PriceBookId__c
```

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that using text fields with an id is considered bad practice. Is that actually true? Nonetheless, I do think this is a possible solution to my problem. Thanks

Comment: While its not great, it is an acceptable compromise in cases where a lookup isn't feasible.